# Betweenness Problem for Binary Comparisons is NP-Complete

Tags: time-complexity

I have a very simple question and wanted to check whether my answer is correct.

Suppose we are given a list of comparisons $x_1>x_2,..,x_k>x_i$ then consider the decision problem asks whether the ordering $>$ can be made transitive and complete over all the X.

My impression is that such a decision problem is NP-complete. Here is my proposed solution.

1. Any solution can be checked in polynomial time, suffice to verify each comparison from the solution ordering.
2. To show it is NP-complete, I show that the *Betweenness Problem* with triple type (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness) is reducible to ours.

Proof of 2):
The Betweenness problem asks exactly our question but has ordering of type $x_1>x_2>x_3$.
But of course each such statement can be translated to $x_1>x_2$, $x_2>x_3$ this is done in at most (?) than polynomial time.

I just wanted to check whether this solution is correct and complete? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem can be solved in linear time. Construct a directed graph on the vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, with an edge $i \to j$ for every comparison $x_i < x_j$. There is a linear order compatible with the given comparisons iff the digraph is acyclic. (See [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was my hope actually. Could you elaborate on which part of my attempt is incorrect? It seems clear that the reduction is then not in polynomial time, but that's not obvious to me. Any help would be great.

Comment: A betweenness constraint is "$x_i < x_j < x_k$ or $x_i > x_j > x_k$".

Comment: I see! thanks so much, that clarifies everything.

Comment: So, this is actually tractable in time linear in the number of pairs ("comparisons"); suggest you mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is wrong. In particular the Betweenness problem is not what you claim it to be.
In the Betweenness problem you are given a collection of triples $(x_i, x_j, x_h)$ and you want to place $x_j$ between the occurrences of $x_i$ and $x_h$. Notice that there is no requirement saying that $x_i$ must precede $x_j$.
I.e., both $\langle x_i, \dots, x_j, \dots, x_h \rangle$ and $\langle x_h, \dots, x_j, \dots, x_i \rangle$ are valid orders.

Your problem is easily solvable in polynomial time.
Let $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be the set of input elements and let $m$ be the number of comparisons you are given in input, where the $i$-th comparison is $c_i > c'_i$ (with $c_i, c'_i \in X)$.
Create the directed graph $G=(X, E)$ where $E = \{ (c'_i, c'i) : i =1,\dots,m \}$.

Your problem admits a solution if and only if $G$ is acyclic. If it is, a solution can be found by computing a topological order of $G$.

Comment: Yes, thanks to your comment and Yuval's earlier comment, I understand my mistake now, thanks a lot!